# Timeline JS API for date selection

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know any API calls for Timeline JS used here

http://timeline.knightlab.com

It seems to only support JSOn objects but it doesn't actually have any API calls such as to jump to a date etc.

Comment: I need that too. That would be cool if we could also add, update and/or remove events from the timeline.